# Tomcat creates 58 sessions for every user

Tags: azure, session, tomcat

So here is my problem. I have a web application built with spring + jsf and running on a tomcat 7 server. When running it locally no problem occurs. When I tried to put it on an Azure ubunto virtual machine everything worked fine except for the fact that when I open tomcat manager I see that 58 sessions are running although I'm the only one running the application thing that does not happen on my windows local machine. [Local tomcat manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHMAu.png) [Virtual machine tomcat manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzqhN.png)

Comment: Most likely because jsessionid from client gets lost somewhere, and hence the server thinks every request is a brand new session

Comment: I don't think so because it happes only at the first entry to the application then only one session will be kept alive and the other sessions will desipire